# How to add an Auth Token in every request using AFIncrementalStore?

Tags: ios, afnetworking, afincrementalstore

I have an iOS + Rails 3.1 app, and I'm using **AFIncrementalStore** for the client-server communication.

I have implemented Token Authentication on my Rails server according to this tutorial: http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/

I now want to include the `&auth_token=XXXXXXXX` in *every* request from client to server, including POST requests. How would I do that? I haven't found the solution in this related post: [Using AFIncrementalStore with an Auth token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966548/using-afincrementalstore-with-an-auth-token)

**UPDATE:** this is my first code attempt, but doesn't seem to send the `auth_token`:

(inside my *AFIncrementalStoreHTTPClient* sub-class)

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestForFetchRequest:(NSFetchRequest *)fetchRequest withContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[super requestForFetchRequest:fetchRequest withContext:context] mutableCopy];
    NSMutableString *requestBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [requestBody appendFormat:@"&%@=%@", @"auth_token", @"xkT2eqqdoNp5y4vQy7xA"];
    [request setHTTPBody:[requestBody dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    return request;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I skimmed your question (sorry!), and my sample code below works for a regular AFHTTPClient, but not AFIncrementalStore.  The same basic approach will work, though, and there's [sample code at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13993836/1445366) that should point you in the right direction.

---

You can't just append `&auth_token=whatever` to the end of your HTTP body in all cases.

You probably want to override your `getPath...` and `postPath...` methods with something like:

```
- (void)getPath:(NSString *)path 
     parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters 
        success:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
        failure:(void (^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    if (parameters) {
        // Make a mutable copy and add the "token" parameter to the dictionary
        NSMutableDictionary *mutableParams = [parameters mutableCopy];
        [mutableParams setObject:@"whatever" forKey:@"token"];
        parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:mutableParams];
    } else {
        parameters = @{@"token" : @"whatever"};
    }

    [super getPath:path parameters:parameters success:success failure:failure];
}
```

This approach will allow AFNetworking to appropriately encode your parameters depending on your specific request and encoding settings.

If you are rolling your own `AFHTTPRequestOperation` objects instead of using the convenience methods (you probably aren't), just make sure you include the token in `parameters` **before** you create your NSURLRequest like so:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"GET" path:path parameters:parameters];
```

Comment: I've studied the linked article before, but *requestForFetchRequest* is only called for the initial GET (index) request and I don't know how to handle POST (create) etc.

Comment: You wouldn't use `requestForFetchRequest` because a fetch request is for GETting data, not creating it.  You should use `requestForCreatedObject` if it's a new object (POST) or `requestForUpdatedObject` if it's an update (PUT).

Comment: You can override `representationOfAttributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes ofManagedObject` to add your auth token to all PUT and POST requests (just add your auth token to the dictionary.)  Override `parametersForFetchRequest` similarly to add your auth token to all GET requests.

Comment: Thanks, `representationOfAttributes` was the key!